# How should the difference between rhetoric and sophistry be characterized when the "criterion" of truth is consensus?

Tags: rhetoric, truth-definition, sophistry

According to Plato/Aristotle, [rhetoric](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-rhetoric/) is the art of effective or persuasive speaking or writing to persuade another of the truth of a proposition. [Sophistry](https://iep.utm.edu/sophists/#H4), on the other hand, came to be known as a supposedly disingenuous use of rhetoric to persuade another of the "truth" of a proposition known to be untrue or whose truth value is unknown.

(1) Can the difference between rhetoric and sophistry still be articulated if we take consensus (agreement within a conversational community of "experts" in a domain) as the meaning [or practical surrogate] of "truth," rather than the currently controversial word-world "correspondence" envisioned by Plato and Aristotle?

(2) How, if at all, should/would the  characterization of the difference between the two concepts change in a world where truth means consensus (*as defined below*), rather than word-world correspondence?

I edited the query above in response to the comments (and answer), allow me, additionally, to further elaborate what I mean by "consensus," by quoting CS Pierce's definition of truth:

> All the followers of science are fully persuaded that the processes of
> investigation, if only pushed far enough, will give one certain
> solution to every question to which they can be applied.…The opinion
> which is fated to be ultimately agreed to by all who investigate, is
> what we mean by the truth.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148855/discussion-on-question-by-gonzo-how-should-the-difference-between-rhetoric-and-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Double Knot your comment:"If truth were some consensus not unlike some scientific community, then good faith rhetoric would just simply need to check the validity/objectivity of the said consensus position with its poll and persuade others such an objective result. Essentially becomes an honest professional journalist. Sophists would simply need to persuade people for a false or fictional consensus if such is a goal for them..."  Is precisely the kind of answer I was looking for, and should be left in comments section because it is actually relevant to the question -- unlike those removed...

Comment: ...which constituted a debate re the definition of "truth, which I had asked to be assumed to be consensus.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between rhetoric and sophistry is not dependent on how you define truth. Take two truths- one of which is a statement that corresponds with reality, the other a statement in accord with public consensus. I could  use certain tactics of language to try to convince you that they are true or to try to convince you they are false when I know them to be true- in the former case I would be employing rhetoric and in the latter sophistry. How the truths are defined is irrelevant. I have always understood sophistry to mean the use of verbal tricks to mislead- it is a very widespread practice.

Answer (score 1):

This particular question gets quite subtle, quite quickly…

First, let me point out that whenever we talk about 'consensus', we are talking about a form of sociopolitical *power*. It doesn't matter whether the thing we are reaching consensus about is expressly political; establishing consensus is an assertion of power of the form: "We must all agree that…". 'Truth' (in this sense) is a power-claim, regardless of anything else it might be.

Now, when we talk about power, we should recognize that power is not unitary; it comes in various forms.  Habermas broke it down into four basic types, each with its own form of rationality:

- Teleological rationality: power equates to success in a given context, so rational behavior involves seeking out success. This is typical in the business world.
- Normative rationality: power equates to conformance to norms, so rational behavior involves interpreting, defending, and regulating adherence to established norms. We see this often in religious and cultural conservatism.
- Dramaturgical rationality: power equates to character, so rational behavior involves self-promotion, other-denigration, the establishment of virtue and authenticity, etc. We see this in both the arts and politics proper, where establishing status and prestige trumps (no pun intended) many other concerns.
- Communicative rationality: Power equates to robust and consistent argumentation, so rational behavior involves discussion, investigation, self-reflection, and detailed explanation.  This mode is most prominent in academia and (proper) journalism.

So to the question, Plato and Aristotle were trying to get at this distinction in power modes. Rhetoric in the sense they mean it is essentially a form of communicative rationality. The aim of rhetoric is to persuade (gain power) through argument, irrespective of character, norms, or end-goals. Sophistry as they saw it fell into the dramaturgical mode: the effort to establish one's character as a superior debater, irrespective of the argument being made. You can see why Plato and Aristotle might have found sophistry annoying, but it is a difficult distinction to make in the best of cases, and sophists will inevitably see any discussion of this point as an attack on their character (as it would appear in their mode of rationality), not as an effort to reach communicative consensus.

Comment: +1 The interjection of Habermas into the analysis is always enlightening.

Comment: No Ted, consensus is NOT always and necessarily power dynamics, a matter of power modes. And the purpose/reason of persuasion is Not always and necessarily about "gaining power."   These are claims that you may successfully [and tragically] be indoctrinating your undergraduates with, but they are NOT the universals you purport them to be.   I may, for instance, want to persuade you to not jump off a cliff because I want to preserve your life, NOT because I wish to exert any power (in any of its forms) over you.

Comment: @gonzo: Social power is not synonymous with social control. If you try to persuade me not to jump off a cliff (or to do anything) that persuasion is a form of power: an effort to convince me to do something other than what I intended to do. Power is ubiquitous; it doesn't stop being power merely because we agree to it.

Comment: I tried to add the qualifier that you were no jumping not bc you were suicidal, but because you believed that your artificial glued on feathers would sustain flight (but the attempted edit was too late).  To tell [persuade] you that you are wrong to jump [if you wish to continue live] is NOT an attempt to exert power over you, but to inform you an erroneous belief.  Another for instance, is it an exercise of "power" to tell you that 2+2 does not=5, but 4?

Comment: And of course the question gets "subtle" quickly.  That's why I asked it.  The concept of "power", however, unless I am missing something,  fails to explicate the difference between truth as correspondence and truth as consensus.  Unless, I suppose, your intention is to equate "sophistry" with an exercise of power.

Comment: @gonzo: informing someone of an erroneous belief is most certainly an exercise in power; knowledge is a form of authority. Often it's appreciated, sometimes it's resented, but it's still power. And I meant to suggest that it doesn't matter whether we think of truth as reality-correspondence or consensus. Either way the assertion of a truth is a power claim. When theists say "God commands us..." it makes no practical difference whether the term 'God' corresponds to a real object or a social convention. The intent is to establish authority and power.

Comment: To say that every assertion of a truth is a power claim is in a trivial sense irrefutable and bears little or no cognitive value.

Comment: @gonzo: trivial irrefutable assertions are the basis of logic; they are the solid foundation that arguments are built on. You may have a valid rhetorical complaint that I am using the term 'power' in an unfamiliar way, in which case we can discuss using a different term. But try not to throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: As always, Ted, your sophistic rhetoric is impeccable.  Conflating, without the slightest qualification, knowledge/truth claims with power/dominance claims amounts to shear pancratism, or to use your locution the "throwing out the [knowledge] baby out with the [power] bathwater.   Far from unfamiliar, your use of the term power (and identity of the two concepts) amounts to a well-known [almost hackneyed] Nietzschean critique/perspective, wherein the will to truth is [really] a will to power (ala trojan horse], and later to half baked Foucaultian sloganeering about regimes of pouvoir/savoir.

Comment: @gonzo: Pancratism.....? At any rate, I'm not interested in a spitball fight. You do you, k?

Comment: Namaste. And good luck with your undergrads, young man.  Oh, and btw, "pancratist," of greek etiology meaning athlete/pugilist, has come in some circles to denote the totalizing tendency to reduce all social relations/processes (including knowledge production) to unspecified patterns of dominance. Your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your use of the word 'controversial' about the correspondance theory, is more controversial than that theory.

It was a very widespread belief that the Sun orbits the Earth. That was wrong. Consensus, and scientific consensus are different things. The idea of consensus as a criterion for truth, hides ignores or discards, choosing *who's* consensus matters. For instance, a mob howling for blood over an incident is not usually considered to make mob justice correct.

When we talk about scientific consensus, we are talking about something formed in Socratic dialogue so with a mutual interest in finding the right answer, and a consensus based on accounting for all the evidence and based on evidence, and also that uses heuristic rules like parsimony and avoiding under- and over-determination, unfalsifiability, and considers hypothesis error types. So saying consensus is the criteria, is usually really a shorthand, rather than a criterion of just accepting whatever the absolute majority vote is on the truth of every assertion.

Plato had in mind truth of correspondance to categories, eg love; which is metaphysical-realism, ie with 'the forms'. Aristotle was used to bolster a similar approach by Aquinas, and  other of hid statements to support a semantic approach to truth by Ockham and others, so truth as about correct use of signifiers.

The traditional competitors to the correspondance theory post Classical times are, pragmatic accounts, coherentism, verificationist and other epistemic theories of truth. The key is the inclusion of relativist and anti-realist attitudes to truth (although also idealist and realist accounts can be involved under these too, eg pluralism).

Regardless of your criterion for truth, there has to be a process for working out if it applies, eg debate. Even for consensus, like in a jury trial, arguments have to be made, evidence shown, for the jury to be able to come to a proper consensus - and as we know criminal trials are prime arenas for rhetoric, and sophistry (like "If the glove fits you must aquit!" in the OJ Simpson trial).

Making a sharp distinction between the sophist and the philosopher, I would associate more with Socrates. His issue was that a Sophist becomes an instrument of their paymaster, an enabling intelligence for someone presumably less capable of thinking through the consequences of their goals or of arguing for them (or they wouldn't be hiring an advocate). Harry Ramsden framed used the term 'bullshit' for pursuasion without regard to truth, and we recognise those who champion that in advertising executives, political lobbyists, and tax lawyers, among others - modern sophists.

Mechanisms exist for how people are allowed to try and change consensus.

> "I could not dig; I dared not rob: Therefore I lied to please the mob.
> Now all my lies are proved untrue And I must face the men I slew. What
> tale shall serve me here among Mine angry and defrauded young?"
>
> -Rudyard Kipling

We have to hope pursuaders face consequences for using lies and criminality to pursuade, before the consensus is forced to shift to recognising the consensus was wrong.

Rhetoric is just taught argumentation and pursuasion, so it's neutral.

For Socrates listening to your conscience, your daimon, is core to serving truth over paymaster, and for him it was worth drinking hemlock rather than contradict it.

Comment: +1 "His issue was that a Sophist becomes an instrument of their paymaster, an enabling intelligence for someone presumably less capable of thinking through the consequences of their goals or of arguing for them (or they wouldn't be hiring an advocate)." Not that different from PR flacks or pettifogging lawyers who use their skills without regard to the pursuit of truth in the philosophical sense of pursuing non-disingenuous conceptual analysis in accordance with the principle of charity.

Comment: Note that my original query did NOT include the qualifying term "controversial", which was a term first used in Conifold 's revision/edit (and I add @Conifold just in case he wants to defend it) see the comments (that were sent to some kind of chat room by Mr. Thomas) after the question above.   My original Query was,,,

Comment: How should the difference between rhetoric :the art of effective or persuasive speaking or writing [to, at its best, according to Plato/Aristotle, in good faith/ingenuously persuade another of the "truth" of a "true" proposition], and sophistry-- [according to Plato/Aristotle] the bad faith/disingenuous use of rhetoric to persuade another of the "truth" of a proposition known to be untrue [or whose truth value is unknown]...

Comment: be characterized when the criteria for "truth" (for whether a proposition is true or false) is "consensus" (agreement within a conversational community of "experts" in a domain), rather than [isomorphic word-world] "correspondence"?

Comment: Had you read my original closely you would have noticed that I defined "consensus" as an "agreement within a conversational community of "experts" in a domain," and hence refrained from saying that "The idea of consensus as a criterion for truth, hides ignores or discards, choosing whose consensus matters. For instance, a mob howling for blood over an incident is not usually considered to make mob justice correct."

Comment: @gonzo: But communities of experts generally reach consensus, by using specific methodologies to give evudence, for what is isomorphic to the world... Consensus is still a shorthand

Comment: Again, please note that in my definition I used the concept "CONVERSATIONAL community," intending to incorporate precisely what you deem to be lacking [discourse/debate and the giving and taking of evidence] in my def.  Using the complex concept, for instance, ala Richard Rorty, who practically coined the term..  In fact, he reccomends...

Comment: ..."that we keep the conversation going rather than pretend to rigorously move toward knowledge of the real world, truth, or consensus under ideal conditions. In Consequences of Pragmatism Rorty argues in favor of the pragmatic approach to knowledge. He sums up one of its characteristics, saying that pragmatism “...is the doctrine that there are no constraints on inquiry save conversational ones — no wholesale  constraints derived from the nature of the objects, or of the mind, or of
language, but only those retail constraints provided by the remarks of our
fellow inquirers.”